# How to get text to display like orginal input from text area

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been trying to format string that get from the text area. I want it shows look like it original from text area input. You will see I've use many function so, please advice me if it doesn't matter to use.

PHP

```
$detail = nl2br(addslashes($_POST['detail']));
$detail = trim($detail);
$detail = str_replace("\r\n","",$detail);
//remove html tags except br prevent it show as html style
$detail = strip_tags($detail, '<br>');
// don't allow consequent new line 
$detail = preg_replace('#(<br */?>\s*){2,}#i', '<br /><br />', $detail);
```

Example input string from text area, and i want it show like this when i `echo $detail`

```
#include <iostream>

using namesspace std;

int main(){
return 0;
}

The most tragic<br /> 
<h1> thing in the world</h1>

 is a man of genius who is not a man of honor.
```

But below is results that I've got, I know it's because i use `strip_tags`. now, i have no idea please help. You will see some text disappear, `<iostream>` `<br />` `<h1>` and ect.

```
#include

using namesspace std;

int main(){
return 0;
}

The most tragic

thing in the world

is a man of genius who is not a man of honor.
```

Another example if this is an input, it should display the same. but for my code, there is nothing display.

```
<textarea rows="7" cols="50" onkeyPress="return addP(event,this)"></textarea>
```

Comment: try to add $detail = htmlspecialchars($detail);

Comment: It seems to work but real new line have replaced too. they are displaying in single line.

Comment: try using `nl2br()` also.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
$detail = htmlspecialchars($detail);
```

for new line, use `PHP_EOL` variable, or replace your `<br>` with `\n`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php